# Input power unit for Heavy Duty spool hose

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, applied-mechanics, hydraulics, mining-engineering

I'm trying to design a machine for spooling a hose at a mining application.

Considering all hose length, mass, spooling diameter and pump the peak torque would be of To = 10267 Nm.
It sounds a lot but the spool diameter had some constrains for fitting a coupling joint inside of it.

For operational time a spool rotation of *N*o = 2,5rpm would be satisfactory.

My problem is finding a hydraulic motor for it which would suit a direct coupling with a worm gear direct reduction, maybe I need a more complex transmission system with auxiliary chains.

Any hints on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Lots of hydraulic motors are made - what have you looked at?

Comment: Done some more research and I found some good orbital motors candidates.

Spec sheet says its maximum continuous speed is of 190 rpm and continuous torque of 900 Nm. But for the applied transmission ratio of about 15:1, I'd only need 40 rpm. So If I lower the flow rate while sustaining the pressure would I still get the maximum torque?
I'm assuming that on a fixed displacement motor, rotational speed is solely dependant on flow rate and torque on pressure. Is that correct?

Comment: No, because losses are not a constant for one…

Comment: Coiled tubing ( steel) is old technology in oil production. Search for what drivers they use.